# How to view System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine output in DbgView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, diagnostics, outputdebugstring

I have an ASP.net web-site hosted on IIS, and the code calls:

```
System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("test");
```

*Reminder: You use **Trace**, rather than **Debug**, because **Debug** requires a debug build. Whereas **Trace** always works<sup>1</sup>*

So on the production web-server, i run `DbgView`, and i don't see the OutputDebugString messages.

Why am i doing wrong?

---

The [**DefaultTraceListener**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.defaulttracelistener?view=net-6.0) already automatically outputs the messages as **OutputDebugString**:

> By default, the [Write](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.defaulttracelistener.write?view=net-6.0) and [WriteLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.defaulttracelistener.writeline?view=net-6.0) methods emit the message to the Win32 [OutputDebugString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-outputdebugstringw) function and to the [Debugger.Log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debugger.log?view=net-6.0) method.

What am i doing wrong?

---

The **DefaultTraceListener** is the default trace listener. It is added by default. And by default it outputs text as **OutputDebugString**. For  *and laughter*, i can try adding it **again** to the `web.config`:

```
    <system.diagnostics>
        <trace autoflush="false" indentsize="3">
            <listeners>
                <add name="defaultListener" type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" />
            </listeners>
        </trace>
    </system.diagnostics>
```

But it doesn't help. What am i doing wrong?

---

I'm running [**DebugView**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview) as an administrator.

I also turned in **Capture Global**, because [some cargo-cult programming says that helps:](https://dickvdbrink.github.io/c%23/2015/01/09/CSharp-Logging-using-Trace-and-DebugView.html)

[image]

But it doesn't help. What am i doing wrong?

## Bonus Reading

- [Use System.Diagnostics.Trace and DbgView within a WPF-Application](https://dev.to/kimkulling/use-systemdiagnosticstrace-and-dbgview-within-a-wpf-application)
- [Using DbgView To Capture Debug Traces From An Application](https://nutsaboutnets.com/faqs/dbgview/)
- [Collect .NET applications traces with sysinternals tools](https://lowleveldesign.org/2014/07/30/collect-net-applications-traces-with-sysinternals-tools/)
- [How to make DebugView work under .NET 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429254/how-to-make-debugview-work-under-net-4)
- [How to get Debug.WriteLine to work with other processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647534/how-to-get-debug-writeline-to-work-with-other-processes)
- [How to write to OutputDebugString from ASP.net web-site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12678471/how-to-write-to-outputdebugstring-from-asp-net-web-site)

---

<sup>1</sup>[Doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71301660/12597)